# Don't know why the cell doesn't appear and there isn't the error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I wrote design via code not from autolayout so I draw collection view with a cell when I change the background color for a collection view it changed but the cell doesn't appear.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
         window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)         
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let layout =  UICollectionViewLayout()

        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout) )


        return true
    }

import UIKit

class ViewController:UICollectionViewController {
    var cell : UICollectionViewCell?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Home"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")



        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return cell!
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }


    }
}
```

There is no error but the cell didn't appear.

Comment: Did you try to add a `numberOfSections` method returning 1 ?

Comment: Don't put the collection view delegate methods inside `viewDidLoad`. If you format your code properly the issue would be clear.

Comment: Is the cell a prototype cell? If yes you must **not** register the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Using `UICollectionViewLayout` requires you to manually manage layout attributes, which can be a bit of work and requires a slightly more involved understanding of how `UICollectionView` works under the hood.

The simplest way to achieve what you are trying to do would be simply to change the layout to a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

In your AppDelegate, change

```
let layout =  UICollectionViewLayout()
```

to

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

I might also suggest refraining from capturing a reference to your cell in your controller by removing this line of code:

```
var cell : UICollectionViewCell?
```

Modifying your code in full would thus result in:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)         
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout) )
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer needs also you put `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height);layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)`, where `width` and `height` are constants defined anywhere in the app

Comment: In a playground I ran this in, it didn’t seem to require setting these properties, so in theory it seems not absolutely required. However, in practice definitely, one would certainly wish to size the cells either as above or via the layout’s delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

try to rewrite the class like this

```
    class ViewController:UICollectionViewController {
            override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Home"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")     
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
          let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return cell
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

cell constant not should be part of your class is must be in the collectionviewDatasource Method, and also it not be optional since the `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)` return a

> UICollectionViewCell

not an optional

> UICollectionView?

the problem with cell not bein part of the class is that UICollectionView are Refence type so each row would have a reference to the same cell. and as @rmady suggedted: the main reason was dont put datasource methods inside `override func ViewDidLoad(){`

Comment: have to look to xcode beacuse i dont memorize this but true, dequeueReusableCell retorns a uitableviewCell not a UITableViewCell?, thanks any way

Comment: Don't just post a code-only answer. Explain what was wrong and explain how this answer fixes the problem. That information should be in your answer, not in comments.

Comment: hope that the opinion dont be after all wrong, @rmaddy

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important part - don't but the collection view methods inside of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: ok, but that your first comment in the answer so i ommited, but added to the answer